# How to parse youtube xml without using youtube api

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, youtube

I want to let users in my Facebook application post YouTube videos.
Any user can put a YouTube link in an input text box. The behavior identical to posting a video on their Facebook wall.
The application extracts the video id from the link and creates a different YouTube link.

For example, if the link is: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JBWd_yJPbr8&feature=related 
The id is: `JBWd_yJPbr8` and the request becomes http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/JBWd_yJPbr8

The problem is to parse the returned XML. This is not standard XML, or at least I have not gotten it to work using standard XML parsers. How can i parse this XML? I need a thumbnail, title and description...

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString)))
{
    XmlWriterSettings ws = new XmlWriterSettings();
    ws.Indent = true;
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(output, ws))
    {




            while (reader.Read())
            {
                switch (reader.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element:
                        writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name);
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.Text:
                        writer.WriteString(reader.Value);
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
                    case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
                        writer.WriteProcessingInstruction(reader.Name, reader.Value);
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                        writer.WriteComment(reader.Value);
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                        writer.WriteFullEndElement();
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Tis case is throw exception :

```
case XmlNodeType.Element:
writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name);
```

Element type not valid

Comment: using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString)))...

Answer (score 3):

Using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/), you can parse the returned json response as:

*(I appended `?alt=json` to your url)*

```
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
string s = wc.DownloadString("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/JBWd_yJPbr8?alt=json");

JObject JObj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(s);

var entry = JObj["entry"];
Console.WriteLine("TITLE: " + entry["title"]["$t"]);
Console.WriteLine("DESC : " + entry["media$group"]["media$description"]["$t"]);
foreach (var thumbnail in entry["media$group"]["media$thumbnail"])
{
    Console.WriteLine(thumbnail["url"]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But i need to use ajax request in this case

Comment: @user750487, Ajax? what do you mean? strictly xml? why?

Comment: My mistake :) JSon is ideal for this case. I was used this code yet.Work perfect. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/youmanager.aspx?display=Print
It is a very good example

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the xml - it parses fine.  The problem is the way you are writing your xml.

The code `writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name);` doesn't work where `reader.Name` returns a string like "app:control" - you can't have colons in an element name.

Where the xml has colons in the tag name, it is because the bit before the colon indicates which namespace the tag belongs to.

If you replace the lines:

```
case XmlNodeType.Element:
    writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name);
    break;
```

with

```
case XmlNodeType.Element:
    writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Prefix, reader.LocalName, reader.NamespaceURI);
    break;
```

Your code should run and parse the XML fine.

You will find though that the outputted xml is not what you want, so that code will still need some work.

Comment: @user750487 - if this answered your question, please consider marking it as the accepted answer by clicking on the tick